# Why can I not iterate through the cookies when I perform a request to an url?

Tags: c#, http, cookies, get

I am trying to perform a get request to https://www.footlocker.dk/. I need to obtain the session that is created, when visiting this url.

I perform the request as following:

```
            string url = "https://www.footlocker.dk/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {

                foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("name=" + cookie.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("value=" + cookie.Value);
                    Console.WriteLine("path=" + cookie.Path);
                    Console.WriteLine("domain=" + cookie.Discard);
                    
                }
            }
```

However it doesnt return me any cookies..

I need these cookies, when I want to go ahead and make a post request afterward, to perform a specific action on this url.

Regards!

Comment: Are you sure those cookies are set by the document http response, and not a javascript XHR call?

Comment: No I am not sure about that :S How can I verify this?

Comment: As an example, use your browser's dev tools to inspect the network calls. You can see which request (a document, XHR, etc) set the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Check the response payloads:

You'll see that the call: https://www.footlocker.dk/api/session?timestamp=1611587725706 has a response header like this:

```
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=orfy8ma22lox1nd8wxdyf8h4e.fzcxwefapipdb018883; Path=/; HTTPOnly
```

[image]

The https://www.footlocker.dk/ sets no such cookies. Bear in mind that if you go throug the calls, you'll see multiple cookie sets, and you can't be absolutely sure which one you need to make things work, though I believe that you can get the cookie you need just by making the session call.

The final cookie definition looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That is awesome, thank you very much.

How would it look like if I wanted to store this response header that is returned, so I can use it in the request i want to make afterwards, if you wouldnt mind :S

Comment: You can store the the cookie locally in variables and add them to the subsequent request. If you want to use it in another context then you might need to store in a persistent option like a database.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept useful answers